# Jquery dialog retains old values

Tags: jquery

I have add button when I click on that a jquery dialog opens and it has two fields 
one is text field another is file upload.
when I enter values in it and press submit
the dialog disappears when I again click on add button it retain previous values in dialog. Can any one help me how to clear values when dialog is submitted.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: i want to completely remove or destroy that dialog so that the previous values must not appear when i click the add button again

Answer (score 1):

Add something like `$('#txtname').val("");` to clear the values of text box on submit.